# Запрос на выборку данных sql, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите составить запрос на выборку данных из таблицы mysql.

Есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить значение backlink по одному или нескольким значениям tag. Можно ли это сделать средствами mysql, sql?

Что-то типа

```
SELECT backlink FROM tag_backlink WHERE tag=105 AND tag=236
```

Чтобы получить backlink=663

Заранее благодарен...

Comment: Ну если писать `tag=105 AND tag=236` то точно ничего не выберете, как это tag _одновременно_ может быть 105 И 236, для таких случаев есть ИЛИ (OR). Ну и в ответе ниже представлен IN, как отличная альтернатива

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Да, это понятно. Я написал, чтобы более понятно было что нужно получить и как.

Comment: Было удобнее вам помогать если бы вы оформили таблицу вместо картинки. Ну и sqlfiddle конечно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша таблица это связка в связи многие-ко-многим?
Тогда решение: OR или IN() + подсчет количества найденного.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6acb96/1

```
SELECT backlink 
FROM tag_backlink 
WHERE tag IN (105,236)
GROUP BY backlink
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 2
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267609/mysql-join-query-for-multiple-tags-many-to-many-relationship-that-matches-al
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824561/select-rows-with-multiple-tags-is-there-a-better-way

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, ответ помог. Ваш комментарий выше принят во внимание )

Comment: Не хватает репутации отметить полезность ответа...

Answer (score 0):

по одному:

```
SELECT backlink FROM tag_backlink WHERE tag=105
```

по нескольким:

```
SELECT distinct backlink FROM tag_backlink WHERE tag IN (105,112,121)
```

Comment: Спасибо. IN() работает как OR. Мне необходимо, чтобы отфильтровывалось как AND. Есть такая возможность?

Answer (score 0):

Из ответов и комментариев становится понятна задача (в вопросе ничего не понятно).

> К двум записям с tag=105 И tag=236 надо вернуть значение backlink, при условии, что оно у них совпадает.

Перевести на язык запросов, будет так

```
SELECT t1.backlink 
FROM tag_backlink t1 
JOIN tag_backlink t2 ON t1.backlink = t2.backlink
WHERE t1.tag = 105 AND t2.tag = 236
```